# Unable to save data in sql server 2005 through c#.NET coding

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have a very unusual problem. I made a project in C#.net in vs 2008 and SQL server 2005.
I have two DB to use.
Now, the problem is whenrunning the project on my PC it works fine, but when i install on users PC, through setup, im getting a exception handler error , when im trying to save any data in either of the DBs. However i tried to insert data through INSERT INTO coomand in sql it works fine. And i have no problem in retrieving data.
So any one can help please do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please update your question with the error and any relevant code.

Comment: I don't think it's a code issue, there are probably more clues in the connection string.

Comment: @BabakNaffas he told " but when i install on users PC, through setup, im getting a exception handler error " so it's a code issue and it has error

Comment: I'm not saying it's definitely NOT code, just that a configuration issue is just as likely. And in cases of DB issues, it's more likely the configuration (the connection string) rather than code that utilizes it.

Answer (score 0):

How are you specifying your connection to the database(s)? If you're doing windows authentication, most likely your user's accounts don't have permissions on the database. It could also be that they can't see the database from where they are on the network.

I'd start by pinging the DB server from the user's machine to make sure they can even access the server.

Comment: Yes its through Windows Authentication.
How can i ping the DB???
and the error im getting is 
"arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
the statement has been terminated"

Comment: and also i said earlier i am able to view data in my projects forms but as im inserting or updating through code, im getting "arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime. the statement has been terminated", or sometime excetion handler error .

Comment: How about your user has an 'unusual' default date/time display setting or culture, and your application is passing the date to SQL as a string - and your SQL code is expecting a date ? SQL will happily try to parse the string into a date, not recognise the format and complain. Check your user's datetime formatting defaults, and thier culture settings.